# When running CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE; pgAdmin Connection lost to server

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

When running `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;` pgAdmin Connection lost to server

This is a new install of postgers server

In mypostgresql.conf

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'
```

Also installed
Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015

Relevant system information:

- Windows server 2012
- PostgreSQL v11.5.1
- TimescaleDB v11.1.3.2

Comment: There should be error messages in the Postgres logfile for that.

Comment: Reinstall postgres 10 now i get could not load library /PostgreSQL/10/lib/timescaledb-0.9.2.dll

Comment: I'm assuming you also filed this issue with TimescaleDB. Just responded - may need more info. My suspicion is that there is something going on with how you set up PgAdmin to talk to PostgreSQL. https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1398

Answer (score 2):

Try to do timescaledb-tune on your shell.
You can ran timescaledb-tune during the install also(for windows) or after.
See the documentation.
https://docs.timescale.com/latest/getting-started/installation/windows/installation-windows

Note: after doing the timescaledb-tune, changes need a restart. So it takes a while untill everything is working fine.

Note2: did you restart the server after making changes in the .conf file!? It needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Stop PostgreSQL
2. Uncomment / Add `shared_preload_libraries = 'timescaledb'` in your `postgresql.conf` file
3. Start PostgreSQL
4. Run the Create extension query

That is basically the main step what the tuning exe does. So if you dont want to run the tuning exe just follow the above steps.